# Can CSS Style implement gui python application like wxpython framework

Tags: python, css, user-interface, styles, wxpython

I want to CSS tyle implement on GUI python desktop application with wxpython can it is possible.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific.

Comment: No with WX. You cannot. WxPython uses the standar widgets of the O.S. and they cannot styled with CSS.

You should check QT and Qt Style Sheets Examples.